# Euclidean plane betweenness

Tags: geometry

In the Euclidean plane, $B$ is between $A$ and $C$ if and only if there is a number $t$ with $0<t<1$ and $B = A+t(C-A)$.

The definition I have for betweenness:

$B$ is between $A$ and $C$ if $A,B$ and $C$ are distinct collinear points and if $d(A,B) + d(B,C) = d(A,C).$

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$d(A,B)=|B-A|=t|C-A|$

$C-B=C-A-t(C-A)=(C-A)(1-t)$, so $d(B,C)=|C-B|=(1-t)|C-A|$

See the end?

Reversing this gives inspiration for the converse. Notice that $B-A$ and $C-A$ point in the same direction, and $t=|B-A|/|C-A|$ scales $C-A$ to match $B-A$.

Comment: Rschwied, I now know, from your hint, how to do prove by first assuming that $B = A+t(C-A)$ and arriving that $B$ is between $A$ and $C$. But how can I do the converse? Assuming first that $B$ is between $A$ and $C$ and arriving that $B = A+t(C-A)$?

Comment: @Alex added info for the converse now too.